# Run multiple virtual enviroments in a single Flask or Django

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, python-venv

I am trying to run two pip packages that require separate version requirements. They would run well in separate virtual environments but not in the same.

I want to use these pip packages in the same app - a flask app. Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Quite often some libraries have overly specific restrictions on dependencies.

I recommend to open an issue at their issue tracker and ask for less restrictive permissions.